# @mui/x-date-pickers <DatePicker/> component styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've tried many attempts to style the `@mui/x-date-pickers <DatePicker/>` component to no avail.

I've tried the `sx={{}}` method, I've tried the `style={{}}` method, I've tried the `makeStyles()` method, I've tried `.css` with `!important` method, I've tried the `renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} sx={{}} or style={{}} or size="small"/>` method, I've tried the `<ThemeProvider/>` method too, but none of them work. I'm at a loss of what to do here.

I also tried asking ChatGPT and it couldn't help me either. I'm starting to think the component is not able to be styled.

What I need to do is simply be able to change the height of the whole component. Here's some example code:

```
import React from "react";

export default const Component = () => {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      fullWidth
      views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
      openTo="month"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => setVaue(newValue)}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        <TextField
          {...params}
          size="small"
        />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default const Component = () => {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      fullWidth
      views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
      openTo="month"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => setVaue(newValue)}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        <TextField
          {...params}
          sx={{ height: '50px' }}
        />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

export default const Component = () => {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      fullWidth
      views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
      openTo="month"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => setVaue(newValue)}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        <TextField
          {...params}
          style={{ height: '50px' }}
        />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Some clarification on how I can style the `<DatePicker/>` and not `<DesktopDatePicker/>` or other variations from `@mui/x-date-pickers` is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DatePicker
    label="from"
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            variant: 'outlined',
            InputProps: {
                sx: {
                    borderRadius: 24
                }
            },
            sx: {
                borderRadius: 24
            }
        }
    }}
/>
```

[image]